# Converting Magento .sh patch file to a list of patched files

Tags: patches, ssh

What's the easiest way to convert .sh file that lists Magento patch changes to a list of modified files, that can be uploaded via FTP?

I tried to use SSH to apply a patch but for some reason not all files are changed - despite the fact that they appear on a list of changed files. Then I've found ready file packages [here](http://magecomp.com/blog/how-to-install-supee-6788-with-or-without-ssh/) but the one for the version 1.9.0.1 seems to contain changes that are not in the .sh file(the package for 1.7.0.2 was fine though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch files don't contain the full file source, they just contain the respective lines that have changed.

So whilst you could extract a list of changed file names, you cannot extract the full file contents.

The only way you could do this, would be to patch another store, then diff the file changes and copy changed files as necessary - *but if you could do this, I bet you'd probably just patch your store to begin with.*

Comment: Thanks Ben, that seems like a good solution. The whole issue boiled down to the fact that I misunderstood the output of patch script. When the message is `patching file xxx` but it shows after `ERROR:...` message the patch isn't actually applied. The error message often appears because some files have content different than expected. I then copied patched files that seemed to be taken from incorrect version and it started... Lesson: always first run ssh, if it fails try to ftp core versions of the files and run again. Only now if it fails attempt direct ftp patch.

Comment: Remember that you can always run `patch.sh -R` to remove the patch